# How can I find all prime numbers from array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, primes

I want to find all prime numbers from array and print them in main class.

```
  public List<Integer> getListOfPrimes(int[] source) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
            if (primeCheck(source[i] == true)
                result.add();
        }
        return result;
    }

    private boolean primeCheck(int value) {
        if (value < 2) return false;
        for (int i = 2; i <= value / 2; i++) if (value % i == 0) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

I have int[] source = {2,4,5,8,13,22}

And i want return a list of prime numbers: 2,5,13

Comment: Translating to English would make the code more readable.

Comment: see https://www.javainterviewpoint.com/prime-number-program-in-java/

Comment: The code is working properly, but you are printing " Prime Numbers: " after the numbers found...

Comment: You can make the code clearer if you take out `array1[i] == 0` and put it in your logic that finds whether the number is prime. For example, after your `if (array1[i] == 1)`, you could put in `else if (array1[i] == 0) isPrime = false;`. This is advisable, because it makes it easier to understand code if it does only one thing. Right now, your print logic also has a part of the prime check logic in it. You could also handle the two cases plus negative numbers by writing `if (array1[i] <= 1) isPrime = false;`. As for your question, what output are you getting?

Comment: Your code checks each number in `array1` to see if it's prime, and if it is, it prints `array1[i] + " ,"`. This part should work as expected with all the primes being on one line in the format `"2 ,3 , 3 ,2 ,"`. That looks a little weird and you can fix it up, but the main problem here is you then print `" Prime numbers: "` on that same line followed by a newline, giving you something like `"2 ,3 ,3 ,2 , Prime numbers: "`. Is this the output you're seeing? Are you asking how to make the format better, or is it outputting the wrong numbers?

Comment: Problem is with outputting, when i run the code i dont see anything, wrote the sout in main and nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does what it's supposed to, but it's a bit confusing.

As an improvement, you could wrap the prim check in a function, making the rest of the code easier to read:

```
private boolean primeCheck(int value){
    if(value < 2) return false;
    for(int i = 2; i <= value / 2; i++) if(value % i == 0) return false;
    return true;
}
```

The prime numbers can then be output number by number, as in your example:

```
System.out.print("Prime Numbers: ");
for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if(primeCheck(array1[i])) System.out.print(array1[i] + ", ");
}
System.out.println("");
```

or as a whole by packing primes into a list:

```
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if(primeCheck(array1[i])) result.add(array1[i]);
}
System.out.println("Prime Numbers: " + Arrays.toString(result.toArray()));
```

A fully functional test project:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 });
    }

    public Main(int[] array1) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            if(primeCheck(array1[i])) result.add(array1[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("Prime Numbers: " + Arrays.toString(result.toArray()));
    }

    private boolean primeCheck(int value){
        if(value < 2) return false;
        for(int i = 2; i <= value / 2; i++) if(value % i == 0) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

A modification of the example that returns the result as a `List<Integer>`.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        List<Integer> result = main.getListOfPrimes(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 });

        // Print array from list
        System.out.println("Prime Numbers: " + Arrays.toString(result.toArray()));

        // Iterate list
        for(int i: result) 
            System.out.println(i);
    }

    public List<Integer> getListOfPrimes(int[] source) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
            if(primeCheck(source[i])) result.add(source[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private boolean primeCheck(int value){
        if(value < 2) return false;
        for(int i = 2; i <= value / 2; i++) if(value % i == 0) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have any further questions about my answer, feel free to post them here as a comment. I would then expand my answer accordingly. I'm reluctant to do it via dm because I've had ambivalent experiences with it. I hope you understand that.

Comment: Okay, thank u, so first of all i want to make this code to return the specific numbers from array, ex. array [ 1, 2 , 3, 4, 5, 6] and method return prime numbers and print 2, 3 ,5 .

Secondly how do i can make a method which find number with most dividers.

Comment: For the first part of the question, I've added to my answer. For the second part I recommend looking for the solution in SO or asking a new question in SO.

Comment: THANKS so much for ur help. i hope in future it could be easier for me

Answer (score 1):

The code sample you provided seems too convoluted for the required task with that nested loop.
When I used to look up algorithms to find a prime number I came across [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/prime-number-program-in-java) sit site (please note there are multiple websites that present the same code).

In your situation I'd make a static method which accepts an int[] as parameter and modify the n variable in the example below to extract an integer from the array to test if it is prime.

```
public class PrimeExample{    
 public static void main(String args[]){    
  int i,m=0,flag=0;      
  int n=3;//it is the number to be checked    
  m=n/2;      
  if(n==0||n==1){  
   System.out.println(n+" is not prime number");      
  }else{  
   for(i=2;i<=m;i++){      
    if(n%i==0){      
     System.out.println(n+" is not prime number");      
     flag=1;      
     break;      
    }      
   }      
   if(flag==0)  { System.out.println(n+" is prime number"); }  
  }//end of else  
}    
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).